# pandas chained indexing: how can we predict whether a view or a copy is created?

Tags: pandas

I have a specific question on pandas (v1.5.1) chained indexing. I know this issue has been discussed a lot and there are many questions regarding copies and views of data frames in SO. I also know how to properly set values using a single accessor and by avoiding chained indexing.

Still, I would appreciate your help so that I understand what is going on.

The code below makes two attempts:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {"x": 2**np.arange(5),
        "y": 3**np.arange(5),
        "z": np.array([45, 98, 24, 11, 64])}
index = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

# attempt 1
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index).astype(dtype={"z": int})
print('-- attempt 1 --')
print('same base I : ',df.loc["a":"c"]["z"].to_numpy().base is df.to_numpy().base)
print('same base II: ',df.loc["a":"c"]["z"].to_numpy().base is df.to_numpy().base)
print('is view: ',df.loc["a":"c"]["z"]._is_view)
print('is copy: ',df.loc["a":"c"]["z"]._is_copy)
# SettingWithCopyWarning, df unmodified
df.loc["a":"c"]["z"] = 0


# attempt 2
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index).astype(dtype={"z": int})
print('-- attempt 2 --')
print('same base I : ',df["z"].loc["a":"c"].to_numpy().base is df.to_numpy().base)
print('same base II: ',df["z"].loc["a":"c"].to_numpy().base is df.to_numpy().base)
print('is view: ',df["z"].loc["a":"c"]._is_view)
print('is copy: ',df["z"].loc["a":"c"]._is_copy)
# df modified
df["z"].loc["a":"c"] = 0
```

The first attempt does not modify the data frame. The second one does. I would like to be able to predict this outcome.

The output of the code is

```
-- attempt 1 --
same base I :  False
same base II:  True
is view:  True
is copy:  <weakref at 0x000002A1B3868310; to 'DataFrame' at 0x000002A1B37D68E0>
-- attempt 2 --
same base I :  False
same base II:  True
is view:  True
is copy:  None
<ipython-input-719-49005df16cfc>:15: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.loc["a":"c"]["z"] = 0
```

I thought that I could use .to_numpy().base to predict the different outcome of the two attempts. Unfortunately, this does not help. In addition, repeating the base check gives different outcomes that is even more confusing. What is going on?

I have also included calls to the internals ._is_view and ._is_copy in case it helps, although I do not understand their behaviour either.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: The .astype(dtype={"z": int}) is superfluous but it seems it makes a difference. Even more confusing.

Comment: I have the impression that setting the value of a whole column to 0 changes the data types from int32 to int64 and this may have something to do with at least whether the data frame is modified or not.